# Compilation Errors in Procedure of Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, procedure, pls-00103

I receive the following error when I compile this function:

> Compilation errors for PROCEDURE HAR.REPORT_INCOME_PROC PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following

I have try to google for that, but I cant my fault...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORT_INCOME_PROC IS

BEGIN
  DELETE FROM HAR.REPORT_INCOME;
  INSERT INTO HAR.REPORT_INCOME RI
    (RI.INCOME,
     RI.AREA,
     RI.INCOME_TYPE,
     RI.DATA_DATE,
     RI.CREATE_DATE,
     RI.UPDATE_DATE)
    SELECT SUM(YD.HJJE) DRSR, 
           MDYS.JYDQ SYB, 
           1,
           TRUNC(YD.KDSJ) RQ, 
           (select sysdate from dual) XZSJ,
           (select sysdate from dual) XGSJ
      FROM HYDATA.LD_YD YD 
      LEFT JOIN HYDATA.LD_KHXX KHXX
        ON YD.TYRBH = KHXX.KHBH 
      LEFT JOIN HYDATA.LD_GS GS 
        ON YD.QYDZBH = GS.GSBH 
      LEFT JOIN HAR.REPORT_JY_MDYS MDYS 
        ON YD.QYDZBH = MDYS.GSBH 
     WHERE YD.KDSJ >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'yy')
       AND (YD.YDZT != 5) 
       AND (YD.CYRQZ != '20000000000000000001' OR YD.CYRQZ IS NULL) 
       AND (KHXX.KHLB != 4 OR KHXX.KHLB IS NULL)
       AND (GS.GSJC NOT LIKE '%F%' OR GS.GSJC IS NULL) 
     GROUP BY TRUNC(YD.KDSJ), MDYS.JYDQ
     ORDER BY MDYS.JYDQ ASC, TRUNC(YD.KDSJ) DESC; 
COMMIT;
END;
```

Here is the error

> ```
> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the
> following:
>           begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
>           <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
>           current cursor external language Line: 1
> ```

Comment: Is this your real code? It should work. Please copy the real code.

Comment: `(select sysdate from dual)` is useless. Just do `sysdate AS XZSJ`

Comment: Probably `order by` is guilty. It's not needed here. Remove it.

Comment: Committing in procedure is a bad idea. If you do a rollback later you might have some surprises.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will improve my code by advice

Comment: I just copy part of my code. In fact, after server hours' finding bug , I finally find bug in the following part of the code. It seems PL/SQL dont give me the right hint.Anyhow , thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe you need to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on a PLSQL BLOCK when doing DML statements.

try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORT_INCOME_PROC IS

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM HAR.REPORT_INCOME';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO HAR.REPORT_INCOME RI <the rest of your codes>';

END;
```

Comment: OK, I will give it a try. Thanks！(*^_^*)

Comment: SURE, on the other note you have to add another single quotes on strings. e.g. AND (YD.CYRQZ != ''20000000000000000001'' OR YD.CYRQZ IS NULL) .. ALSO please consider the previous comments to optimize your query like removing the ORDER BY etc..